# How do I connect forms to models in Django?

Tags: python, django, database

I've just started learning Django, and I have questions regarding forms and models. 
So what I'm trying to create, in simplified feature, is a user inputs his/her basic information--phone #, instagram account, facebook account, and so on--then the data is stored in database and show up dynamically to the user. Just like social media. But I'm having confusion with forms and models.
What I first did was create forms, like below (forms.py) :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class InputUserInfo(forms.Form):
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    instagram = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    facebook = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    # and so on. Don't mind about which field to use.
```

then I have my views.py file, written as below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import InputUserInfo

def inputuserinfo(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = InputUserInfo(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = InputUserInfo()
    return render(response, 'inputuserinfo.html', {'form' : form }
```

then I have my inputuserinfo.html file, like below:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action='/inputuserinfo/'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type='submit'>Done</button>
</form>
{% endblock%}
```

Now the problem is, **I don't know what to do with my models.py. I don't know which code to write in models.py to store the input data into my database.** 
I would very much appreciate your help guys. :)

Comment: You generally do your model first, then create a `ModelForm` that references the model...

Comment: @JonClements Okay then let's say I've created a model, with ```phone=models.CharField()``` and so on. Then do I have to create forms with the exact same field to get input from user? I appreciate your answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you left out the ModelForm. Is there any reason you arent using Class Based Views. This would be much easier?

Your ModelForm will end up looking something like this

```
    class InputUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
'''user form to create the user profile'''
class Meta:
    model = InputUserInfo
    fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. Thanks a lot. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Django, a **model** is an interface to a particular database.  It will create and issue SQL queries for you.

A **form** is an interface to HTTP "GET" and "POST."  It can generate the HTML to insert into a form-tag (but do not provide the tag itself), and they can interpret the data that is presented to the host from such a form.  Instead of monkeying around with the HTML data yourself, you let the Form object do the heavy lifting, both coming and going.

Django provides many convenience shortcuts, such as **ModelForm,** which is a **Form** that can be based on the content of a **Model.**  It will "quickly produce an acceptable-looking form" when you are in a hurry ... as you often are.  And it can do things like *save()* directly because it knows what model you want to save the data to.